# Armazenar valor em um ArrayList de ArrayList

Tags: java, table, arraylist

Olá, estou com uma dúvida em relação a armazenar o valor que obtenho de uma tabela em um arraylist de arraylist. Como deveria fazer para poder armazenar?

Por exemplo:

```
Private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> valorMatriz = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

String v;

int linha = jTable2.getRowCount();
int coluna = jTable2.getColumnCount();

for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j< coluna; j++){
     valor = jTable2.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
    //código que armazena a variável valor em valorMatriz
     print(valor + " ");
  }
}
```

Pergunta: qual a sintaxe para armazenar a variável v em valorMatriz?

Comment: Esta tendo algum problema? Parece tudo ok, mas não sei, falta contexto melhor.

Comment: Tá meio estranho, o `private` deveria ter `p` minúsculo, e deveria ter um `()` ao final da primeira linha, mas se seu código estiver assim não é nem para compilar. Especifique exatamente o problema que está tendo.

Comment: O problema é a sintaxe em si, não estou conseguindo, apesar de estar procurando, uma maneira (comando) para a armazenar o valor v dentro de valorMatriz

Comment: A falta de () foi só aqui na hr de escrever, mas o private com p minuscúlo não da erro.

Comment: Com o código informado apenas não dá pra detectar o problema. Adicione mais da implementaçao.

Comment: A `string` também está com capitalização errada, deveria ser `String`. Seria uma boa você criar um [mcve] para que fosse possível ajudar-lhe melhor.

Comment: Ainda não vi problema nenhum com o código. Você precisa ser mais específico. Quanto a melhor ou pior, torna a reposta opinativa, do tipo que o site não encoraja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> valorMatriz = new ArrayList<>();

String v;

int linha = jTable2.getRowCount();
int coluna = jTable2.getColumnCount();

for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
    ArrayList<String> arrayLinha = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j< coluna; j++){
        valor = jTable2.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
        arrayLinha.Add(valor);
        print(valor + " ");
    }
    valorMatriz.add(arrayLinha);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer funcionar o que precisava

Comment: @MichaelPacheco , gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789)